# Only a specific variable works for my ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am so confused. I have a form and for now, I send a value into my javascript function. It works with a specific name "bookDate" but whenever I decide to change the name, it gives me an index unidentified error.

HTML FILE:

```
<input name="submit" type="button"                          onClick="postBooking('postbooking.php','targetDiv', pickUpDate.value, pickUpTime.value) " value="Book a Cab!">
```

Javascript:

```
function postBooking(dataSource, divID, bookingDate, bookingTime) {
    if (xhr) {
        var place = document.getElementById(divID);
        var url = dataSource + "?bookDate=" + bookingDate + "&bookTime=" + bookingTime;
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
```

PHP:

```
$pickUpDate = $_GET["bookDate"];
    $pickUpTime = $_GET["bookTime"];
    echo $pickUpDate." ".$pickUpTime;
```

In the javascript, when I change "bookDate" into another name (I change the php GET as well to match) it starts to give an index unidentified message when I click my button. It works fine the way it is so I'm so confused why only that name works.

Comment: If that JS is in a separate file it may be getting cached by your browser and not actually changing in the frontend. Maybe add a log line to see what url is actually being visited or try visiting postbooking.php manually

Comment: Don't forget to refresh the page in your browser before you test.  It's easy to forget to do so.  And, when things really get hinky, do a hard refresh.  Also, bring up your browser's console and use the network tab to see what was actually sent.  That makes it easier to see if reality matches what you were expecting.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks Heaps! I just go into incognito every time I make a change to the script and it seems to be updating everytime.